# go template alternating design between rows

Tags: go

I have a simple template fetching a list of blog posts:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        {{range .Pages}}

        <p class="dialogue dialogue--wide">
            <a href="{{.Slug}}">{{.Title}} </a>
        </p>

        {{end}}
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to alternate the design between posts e.g. the first will use a certain

class like

and the second record (or even and odd records if you prefer) another p e.g.

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest solving this with CSS to save yourself some trouble. You can use `odd` or `even` in `nth-child`:

```
.dalogue:nth-child(odd) {
    // CSS Property   
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the index of the items. Below, I am using the modulo operator to determine if it's odd or even.

```
{{ range $index, $page := .Pages }}
 {{ if eq (mod $index 2) 0 }} odd {{ else }} even {{ end }}
{{end}}
```

Note, I am switching odd and even around. Because the index starts at 0 and not at 1. But when looking at a table, you start counting at 1 and this is also how CSS would behave.

I have implemented the mod function myself using [template.Funcs](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#Template.Funcs).

```golang
t.Funcs(map[string]any{"mod": func(a, b int) int { return a % b }})
```

https://go.dev/play/p/aAupH-4CugV